# jquery ui widget accordion open with external button control

Tags: jquery-ui, widget

how can i open and close Jquery UI Accordian widget with external control (button/anchor).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I figured it out by myself, as shown below.
Suppose this is your jquery UI according consisting of four accordians.

```
        <div id="accordion" class="accordion">
        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">First</a></h3>
            <div>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet.</div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">Second</a></h3>
            <div>Phasellus mattis tincidunt nibh.</div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <h3><a href="#">Third</a></h3>
            <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
        </div>

       <div>
            <h3><a href="#">Fourth</a></h3>
            <div>Nam dui erat, auctor a, dignissim quis.</div>
        </div>


    </div>
```

Now add external anchors with their different ID's

```
    <!-- Enternal Anchor Mossawir -->
    <div>
     <a href="#" id="openfirst">Open 1st</a>
     <a href="#" id="opensecond">Open 2nd</a>
    <a href="#" id="openthird">Open 3rd</a>
    <a href="#" id="openfourth">Open 4th</a>
    </div>
```

Now add  jquery code.

```
         $(function(){

         $("#accordion").accordion({ header: "h3" });


        //this will open 1st accordian.
        $('#openfirst').click(function(){
                  $(".accordion").accordion({active:0});
            });

        //this will open 2nd accordian.
         $('#opensecond').click(function(){
                  $(".accordion").accordion({active:1});
            });

        //this will open 3rd accordian.
            $('#openthird').click(function(){
                  $(".accordion").accordion({active:2});
            });


        //this will open 4th accordian.
       $('#openfourth').click(function(){
                  $(".accordion").accordion({active:3});
            });

        });
```

To add more accordions and anchor, simply add an new id to anchor and in jquery code will give its active parameter. active:0 means 1st accordion, active:1 means the second accordian and so on. this works for Jquery UI accordion.
Here is an example: http://jsfiddle.net/ZRBc6/1/

Comment: demo does not contain jquery UI library, in order to work simply use this code and add jquery UI library!

Answer (score 3):

```
.accordion( "activate" , index )
```

will do this for you. The index can be a zero-indexed number to match the position of the header to close or a Selector matching an element. Pass

```
false
```

to close all (only possible with

```
collapsible:true
```

).

Comment: onclick="$('#accordion').accordion( 'activate' , 0 )" worked for me, simple and effective

Answer (score 0):

I have created a accordian look and feel on buttons external to the divisions. This is how it looks.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function doFunction(buttonId) {
    if(buttonId=="1"){
    document.getElementById("collapseTwo").className = "panel-collapse collapse";
    document.getElementById("collapseThree").className = "panel-collapse collapse";
    }
    if(buttonId=="2"){
    document.getElementById("collapseOne").className = "panel-collapse collapse";
    document.getElementById("collapseThree").className = "panel-collapse collapse";
    }
    if(buttonId=="3"){
    document.getElementById("collapseTwo").className = "panel-collapse collapse";
    document.getElementById("collapseOne").className = "panel-collapse collapse";
    }
}
</script>

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.5/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
  <h2>Simple Collapsible</h2>
  <button id="id1" type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="doFunction('1');" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne">Simple collapsible1</button><br/>
  <button id="id2" type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="doFunction('2');" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseTwo">Simple collapsible2</button><br/>
  <button id="id3" type="button" class="btn btn-info" onclick="doFunction('3');" data-toggle="collapse"  data-target="#collapseThree">Simple collapsible3</button><br/>


<div id="demu"  style="padding-left:15%">
   <div class="panel-group" id="accordion">
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseOne">1. What is HTML?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>HTML stands for HyperText Markup Language. HTML is the main markup language for describing the structure of Web pages. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/html-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseTwo">2. What is Bootstrap?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseTwo" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>Bootstrap is a powerful front-end framework for faster and easier web development. It is a collection of CSS and HTML conventions. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree">3. What is CSS?</a>
                </h4>
            </div>
            <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                <div class="panel-body">
                    <p>CSS stands for Cascading Style Sheet. CSS allows you to specify various style properties for a given HTML element such as colors, backgrounds, fonts etc. <a href="http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/css-tutorial/" target="_blank">Learn more.</a></p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

For Opening you can use active method with index of element to be opened

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
  active:0
});
```

For Closing

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
  active:false
});
```

you can refer customised JQuery UI Accordion Sample at following fiddle
https://jsfiddle.net/Kuldipg/35xp2w0f/