# Open jquery accordion using anchor tag within same page

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I've searched for hours trying to find a solution for this but I can't quite figure this out. Any help would be appreciated. I'm starting to understand jquery a bit but it's mostly Klingon to me, so answers in English would be very much appreciated! :)

I am trying to open an accordion using an anchor tag from within the same page. On page load, the accordion is closed. Everything is working except it will not open upon clicking the link from somewhere else on the page to the accordion tab.

The link to the accordion tab (not sure if this is correct in this case?):

```
<a href="mypage.html/#linkName">Go to accordion tab and open accordion</a>
```

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div class="accordion product1">
    <a id="linkName"><h3>tab Name</h3></a>
    <div>accordion content</div>
</div>
```

This is the code I have so far. What do I need to add to make the accordion open with an anchor tab please?

```
$(function() {
    $( ".accordion.product1" ).accordion({
        header : "a#linkName",
        active: false,
        collapsible: true,
        heightStyle: "content",
        animate: 400
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

here is a great explanation how to do it [jquery ui widget accordion open with external button control](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5480988/jquery-ui-widget-accordion-open-with-external-button-control) . On click event of some tag:

```
$('.some-tag').on('click', function(){
    $( ".accordion.product1" ).accordion({active:0});
});
```

`active:0` the 0 is index of the accordion that you want to open.

#### UPDATE

Add this to accordion:

```
$('.accordion.product1').accordion({
    //... options
    collapsible: false
});
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the help. It was very helpful. What would I need to do to have all instances of the tabs closed on page load? The sample shown has the first instance opened.

Comment: Well depends on how many `a` tags do you have and what kind of logic you want to implement...

Comment: In this case, it's a single instance (only the 1 accordion and 1 link to it). There's a detailed example of a product that I would like to be closed upon page load but open with a link to it, if a visitor was interested in seeing the details.

Comment: see the update, if that's what you were looking for, please set it as an answer.

Comment: No, the accordion is still open on page load.

Comment: Tried "collapsible: true" as well (using the code from the jquery example in case there was an error in my code) but the first div is still open by default. I would like to set it to closed by default if possible?

Comment: I've tried the examples on the linked page a number of different ways and I can not make it closed by default. Also the example "jquery ui widget accordion open with external button control" does not jump to the accordion. It will open it up, but not take the viewer to the accordion. Any help with this would be really appreciated.

Comment: give an `id` to accordion, and then add `href='#id-of-the-accordion'` to `a` tag and it should jump to accordion when clicked.

Comment: Thanks for this Lord Zed! Would you know how to set the default tab to closed? Setting collapsible to false prevented the accordion from closing at all.

Comment: try then changing options to `collapsible: true, active: 0`

Comment: Still not working. Here's a JSfiddle example:
http://jsfiddle.net/ZRBc6/134/
The first instance is still open by default but I want it to be closed. Is this possible?